# How to get common area of two nodes in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, geometry, collision, sknode

First of all, what I want to achieve is a shape node filled with two different, distinct colors (not blended), e.g. top part of a circle is white, bottom is black.

From what I've found, my only option is to [manually create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100888/draw-rectangle-circle-and-triangle-in-spritekit-with-two-colors) paths and color them. That's fine with me, but I first need to know the exact paths.

I'm trying to avoid complex calculations, so my question is - is there any way to get a path describing a common area of two overlapping nodes?

A [simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2r3U.jpg) to illustrate the problem: when the circle collides with the black area, the part of the circle which overlaps black rectangle should change colour - how can I get that overlap area's path?

Comment: dont know any method in spritekit that would do this.  maybe something in core graphics framework could handle this..  but it's a fairly special need.  you may have to do the work from scratch, or dig up the calculations somewhere.

Comment: I see..
I'm putting this task on the shelf for when I'll have a loooot of time. For now, animated fade & blend does the job, even if it's nothing like I wanted originally.
If I finally create a solution, I'll post it as an answer.