# Xcode, SKSpriteKit, can't draw quadrilateral

Tags: sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm using Xcode, SKSpriteKit and am creating a game.

I need my program to draw a quadrilateral in a function.

```
    -(void) DrawQuad {
    //Draw Quadrilateral here with points (a,b), (c,d), (e,f), (g,h)
    }
```

I have already tried other links/help but for some reason, the code I paste doesn't work.

For example, at: [Draw Rectangle/ Circle and Triangle in Spritekit with Two Colors. . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100888/draw-rectangle-circle-and-triangle-in-spritekit-with-two-colors), I try copy and pasting that function into my code (In the .mm file). It doesn't work:

[image]

[image]

Even making the suggested changes in the program still doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SKShapeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013025-CH1-SW18) draws a shape defined by a [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/index.html) path. If I remember correctly, UIBezierPath is not part of that but you can use CGPath instead.

Look at this sample code:

```
SKShapeNode *myNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
myNode.position = CGPointMake(300,300);
myNode.zPosition = 100;
CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, 0, 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, 100, 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, 100, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, nil, 0, 0);
myNode.path = myPath;
CGPathRelease(myPath);
myNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
[self addChild:myNode];
```